# Refused to connect to '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, security, header

I built an API for my clients to get some data and some JS scripts that my clients are injecting in their website to add some UI and functionalities to their checkout page.
The scripts are injected successfully but some of them are getting a CSP error when requesting some of the API's.

- is there a way I can solve this problem from my end, or the clients have to change their CSP from their end?

[image]